# PostgreSQL crashes during count row query

Tags: postgresql, mac-os-x

Currently I have only two tables - small one that works fine and another presumably large one.
When I try to find out row count in pgAdmin I get the following error:

```
The application has lost the database connection:
⁃ If the connection was idle it may have been forcibly disconnected.
⁃ The application server or database server may have been restarted.
⁃ The user session may have timed out.
Do you want to continue and establish a new session?
```

I also checked the Postgres server logs:

```
2020-03-30 03:06:06.764 MSK [37356] LOG:  server process (PID 30712) was terminated by signal 9: Killed: 9
2020-03-30 03:06:06.764 MSK [37356] DETAIL:  Failed process was running: SELECT COUNT(*)::text FROM ios.task_info;
2020-03-30 03:06:06.764 MSK [37356] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2020-03-30 03:06:06.765 MSK [30810] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2020-03-30 03:06:06.765 MSK [30810] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2020-03-30 03:06:06.765 MSK [30810] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2020-03-30 03:06:06.765 MSK [30709] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2020-03-30 03:06:06.765 MSK [30709] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2020-03-30 03:06:06.765 MSK [30709] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2020-03-30 03:06:06.767 MSK [37356] LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
2020-03-30 03:06:06.776 MSK [30816] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2020-03-30 02:51:14 MSK
2020-03-30 03:06:06.818 MSK [30817] FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2020-03-30 03:06:06.853 MSK [30816] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2020-03-30 03:06:06.855 MSK [30816] LOG:  redo starts at 0/4F4DE850
2020-03-30 03:06:06.855 MSK [30816] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/4F4DE888: wanted 24, got 0
2020-03-30 03:06:06.855 MSK [30816] LOG:  redo done at 0/4F4DE850
2020-03-30 03:06:06.862 MSK [37356] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

I run everything on my OS X Catalina laptop and use PostgreSQL 12 EnterpriseDB.

Just in case if it is important - I created the large table sending several large CSV `COPY` queries in my Python script. 
What can be the reason of these errors?

Comment: Somebody or something killed your backend process with `kill -9`. If this were Linux, I'd point to the OOM killer. What is your `work_mem` and `shared` buffers set to? Can you look at the kernel logs?

Comment: I use OS X Catalina. I checked /var/log/system.log - nothing happened/appended there after count query crushes. Also I checked shared_buffers = 128MB in postgresql.conf. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Just to clarify  - in postgresql.conf I see shared_buffers = 128MB and #work_mem = 4MB (commented).

Comment: Well, something external is killing your processes. That is not PostgreSQL's fault. You'll have to figure out who or what does that.

Comment: But it is killing the process right after every "SELECT COUNT(*)" query.

Comment: No, somebody/something is killing the query *while* it runs, not afterwards. You have to find out what that is and disable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I run everything on my OS X Catalina laptop and use PostgreSQL 12
>   EnterpriseDB.

There is a JIT-related problem on this platform and version that leads to the kind of crash you're reporting. It's explained on mailing lists:

[Re: PG v12.2 - Setting jit_above_cost is causing the server to crash](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CA+OCxoz0bWi+R2WpocfkD20Lgrg69z1jQ_SZd-zmdzHW0zt+bg@mail.gmail.com)

At the moment, the workaround seeems to be to `set jit = off` until EDB releases a new version with a fix, hopefully in PostgreSQL 12.3

Comment: Thanks! Seems you are right! I tried SET jit_above_cost = -1; before query and it helped! Strange that even EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT COUNT(*) doesn't work if jit is on.